# How to make a DLL work with Unity in Mac OS X?

Tags: dll, unity-game-engine

I've designed an application in which the user must register himself. For this I've used a Web Service, and the application running in the **Unity Editor** on Mac OS X, or Windows makes the request without errors.

If I build the application as a Windows executable it also works, but when I build the application for **Mac OS X** it no longer works (outside the Editor). The request does not work properly.

In the project I've created **Plugins** folder and introduced both **System.Web** and **System.Web.Services** DLLs.

**Api Compability Level** in Player Settings is **NET 2.0.**

When I try to run the Mac OS X build I get this **error** message in the Log:

```
at System.Net.WebRequest.GetCreator (System.String prefix) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.WebRequest.Create (System.Uri requestUri) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol.GetWebRequest (System.Uri uri) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpWebClientProtocol.GetWebRequest (System.Uri uri) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.GetWebRequest (System.Uri uri) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.GetRequestForMessage (System.Uri uri, System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapClientMessage message) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke (System.String method_name, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at BGWebServiceService.login (.LoginRequestBean bean) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) BGWebServiceService:login (LoginRequestBean)
  at ClientObject.loginAsyncRequest () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I've looked many forums and searched the web and I can't find the answer. I don´t know if it´s necessary to add any other folder, put the DLLs on some other place or do something else in the project.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: The unity tag is used by Microsoft Unity. Don't misuse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found how to make it work.

Only, we have to add /Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/Frameworks/Mono folder into our Framework´s app folder.